# applying required field validation on drop down and date picker in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp

I have a jsp page,I want that a user won't be able to submit the form ,until he has not chosen a value from dropdown list and have not chosen any date from calendar.My codefor jsp is-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>User_Interface</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">




<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker.js">
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function date_comapare()
{

    var d1=document.getElementById("startdate").value; // start date 
    var d2=document.getElementById("enddate").value; //end date 

    if(new Date(d2).getTime() < new Date(d1).getTime()) 
{ 
    alert("Endate date should be greater than start date"); // handle your error validation here 
    return false; 
    }
    else
        {return true}; 
    } 
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="val"]').click(function() {
       if($('input[name="val"]').is(':checked')) { 
           var radioValue = $("input[name='val']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue == "Filling"){
               $( "#Fil" ).prop( "disabled", false );
               $( "#store" ).prop( "disabled", true );
            } else {
                $( "#Fil" ).prop( "disabled", true );
               $( "#store" ).prop( "disabled", false );
            }
       }
    });
    });
</script>
</head>

</head>

<body>
<jsp:useBean id="obj"  class="ref_Database.Refernce_Database" />


<form  method="post" action="All_Mps.jsp">
<b>Select Status</b>
<p><input type="radio" name="val" value="Filling" id="Filling"> Filling</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="val" value="Stored" id="stored"> Stored</p>


Select Reference for filling:<br>
<select name="ref_fill" id="Fil" disabled="disabled"  >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
<br>
Select Reference for storage:<br>

<select name="ref_stored" id="store" disabled="disabled" >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<br><br>
<b>Select Date to be compared</b><br>
<p>


<br />





<input id="startdate" type="text" size="25" name="startdate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('startdate','mmddyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

<input id="enddate" type="text" size="25" name="enddate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('enddate','mmddyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

 <input type="submit" onclick="return date_comapare();" value="Submit" /><br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

User has to chose any one value from any of the dropdown and has to select date and time from the calender.How to make these fields mandatory for the user.

**Output is-**

[image]

EDIT-3
I tried in following way-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>User_Interface</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
    <script src="../dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker.js">

//Date Time Picker script- by TengYong Ng of http://www.rainforestnet.com
//Script featured on JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
//For this script, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com 

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function date_comapare()
{

    var d1=document.getElementById("startdate").value; // start date 
    var d2=document.getElementById("enddate").value; //end date 

    if(new Date(d2).getTime() < new Date(d1).getTime()) 
{ 
    alert("Endate date should be greater than start date"); // handle your error validation here 
    return false; 
    }
    else
        {return true}; 
    } 

</script>






<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#form").validate({
          rules: {
              startdate: {
             required: true
          },
         dp: {
            required: true
          }
       },
       enddate:{
             required: true
          },
       messages: {
           startdate: {
           required: "date is required"
        },
       dp: {
        required: "select one option"
       }
      },
      enddate:{   required: "date is required"
        },
      ignore: "",
      errorClass: 'fieldError',
      onkeyup: false,
      onblur: false,
      errorElement: 'label',
      submitHandler: function () {
          alert("alert");
      }
     });

       $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
           $("#form").valid();
       });
    });
</script>


</head>

<body>


<form  method="post" id="form" action="All_Mps.jsp">
Select Reference:

<select name="ref_logtime" id="dp" >
<option value="">Select</option>

<option value="[2014-10-10 07:17:00.0, 2014-10-10 08:46:00.0]">Ref_Filling-1 [2014-10-10 07:17:00.0, 2014-10-10 08:46:00.0]</option>

<option value="[2014-10-10 08:50:00.0, 2014-10-10 12:50:00.0]">Ref_Storage_1 [2014-10-10 08:50:00.0, 2014-10-10 12:50:00.0]</option>

<option value="[2014-09-08 10:00:00.0, 2014-09-08 11:00:00.0]">Reference-3 [2014-09-08 10:00:00.0, 2014-09-08 11:00:00.0]</option>

<option value="[2014-10-10 08:50:00.0, 2014-10-10 23:50:00.0]">Ref_Storage_2 [2014-10-10 08:50:00.0, 2014-10-10 23:50:00.0]</option>

<option value="[2014-09-01 10:00:00.0, 2014-09-01 11:00:00.0]">Ref_Filling-2 [2014-09-01 10:00:00.0, 2014-09-01 11:00:00.0]</option>

</select>

<br><br>
<b>Select Date to be compared</b><br>

<input id="startdate" type="text" size="25" name="startdate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('startdate','mmddyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

<input id="enddate" type="text" size="25" name="enddate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('enddate','mmddyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

<input class="submit" type="submit" onclick="return date_comapare();" value="Submit" /><br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have already included jQuery library in your code, then why don't you go for [jQuery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/releases) and [this](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan, I will try to implement it with jquery. Thanks for link

Comment: @VinothKrishnan,I tried  but when I leave my field empty, and click on submit no validation is popped up,see my updated question

Comment: Please go through this [LINK](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/master/demo/index.html) has some demo for validation. Let me know if you have difficulties. Save that as a `.html` file and view it in a browser. You will understand.

Comment: I have seen your code, many mismatch in tagging the elements. please rectify that.

Comment: Otherwise the cod eis corrcet???

Comment: Can you please see the links which I have added ,are they correct??At pace of ** $("#commentForm").validate();**, I wrote ** $("#User_vacc1.jsp").validate();**User_vacc1.jsp is name of my jsp page on whcich I want to apply validation

Comment: Not really, you have missed some validate rules part in jquery. Like this `$("#formid).validate({rules: {firstname: "required"}});`

Comment: @VinothKrishnan,please see my edit-2, I included id of the items.But still it didn't worked.What is the mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Does it shows any issue in browser console? (You can check it by pressing f12 button and choose console). If so post the errors.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan,**java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**:is shown,as user has to select some date through this form when I submit the form without entering any details.

Comment: I am not asking for java console. Please check in browser console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74085/discussion-between-tiddi-rastogi-and-vinoth-krishnan).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by JQuery

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
                if ($("#startdate").val() == "" || $("#enddate").val() == "" || $("#Fil option:selected").val() == "" || $("#store option:selected").val() == "")
                {
                    return false;
                }
            })
```

let me know if you think different for the solution.

Comment: I did this,but it didn't worked,I simply copied it and pasted between script tags

Comment: Can you debug the code so you can identify where this condition going wrong.

Comment: It shows error in JavaScript Code ? if yes then for which element among 4 elements ?

Comment: Not able to debug it,Nullpointer exception comes when i submit the form.I'm not able to add breakpoints in it, add bookmark option is coming again and again.I will show u my output window of it.

Comment: You should debug in browser. and JavaScript can be debugged from all browsers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73840/discussion-between-tiddi-rastogi-and-ajay).

Comment: ,i think we are missing out something in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked your issue on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v5HQr/219/) and find the respective code below,

In HTML,

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" value="" name="input" id="input" /> <br>
 <select name="dp" id="dp">
     <option value="">Select any option</option>
     <option value="1">option1</option>
     <option value="2">option2</option>
     <option value="3">option3</option>
  </select><br>

 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And in scripting part,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#form").validate({
      rules: {
          startdate: {
              required: true
           },
          dp: {
              required: true
          },
          enddate:{
              required: true
          }
       },
       messages: {
          startdate: {
             required: "date is required"
          },
          dp: {
             required: "select one option"
          }
          enddate:{   
             required: "date is required"
          }
    },
  ignore: "",
  errorClass: 'fieldError',
  onkeyup: false,
  onblur: false,
  errorElement: 'label',
  submitHandler: function () {
      alert("alert");
  }
 });
   $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
       $("#form").valid();
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your rendered HTML? I cannot assume how your dropdown populating?

Comment: You are wrong, check curley braces under dp field. there is one extra. In both places, join the old chatrrom if possible